# Multer hangs if no filename provided

Tags: node.js, multer

I wanted to see how my server behaved if I didn't provide a filename when uploading an image, and [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) just hangs.  Is there a way I can get `multer` to time out? or throw an error on bad forms?  This would be pretty easy to create a DoS attack against which is why I'm concerned.

Here's the multipart header I'm sending, purposefully omitting the filename:

```
String header = "--" + boundary + LINE_FEED +
// "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + field_name + "\"; filename=\"" + "bitmap.jpg" + "\"" + LINE_FEED +
"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + field_name + "\"" + LINE_FEED +
"Content-Type: " + content_type + LINE_FEED +
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary" + LINE_FEED +
            LINE_FEED;
```

Here's my server code that hangs. `before upload` prints but neither `after upload` or the `Error` statement print out:

```
const Upload = multer( my_multer_options ); //makes use of multer's fileFilter which isn't even touched when a filename isn't provided.
const uploadFiles = Promise.promisify( Upload.fields([{name: "image", maxCount: 1}]) );

try
{
    console.log( "before upload" );  //prints

    await uploadFiles(context.req, context.res);

    console.log( "after upload" ); //never prints
}
catch ( error )
{
    console.log( "Error: " + error ); //never prints
}
```

Comment: related? https://github.com/expressjs/multer/issues/53

Comment: If you cannot find in multer how to deal with the issue, i recommand you to put a timeourt into the express server itself plus configure [limits](https://github.com/expressjs/multer#limits) in multer